# Angular Listening to start and completion of network call(download function) to display progress bar or spinner

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a download function which is initiated by a button click. When that happens I want to display a progress bar/spinner while the network call is happening and then hide the bar/spinner once the download starts.

I'll be using the angular material mat-progress-bar. My idea was to listen to the start of the network call and define it as isLoading= true and its completion which would result in a file link or an error  would set isLoading= false to hide the progress bar eg

```
   <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate *ngIf 
   ="isLoading"</mat-progress-bar>
```

to display and hide the progress bar.

I tried to do this by doing something like :

```
   this.documents.find(document => document.id 
   === element.id).isLoading = true
```

and then defining isLoading as false in my subscribe but thats not doing exactly what i need it do to.

This is my download function:

```
download(element: Document | TDoc, index: 
    number) {if (
    (!this.isTDoc && ! 
    (<Document>element).files.length) ||
    (this.isTDoc && !(<isTDoc>element).url)
    )
     return;

if (this.isTDoc) {
  const url = (<TDoc>element).url;
  const fileName = `${(<TDoc>element).itemName}.pdf`;

  downloadLink(url, fileName);
} else {
  const query = 'index=' + index.toString();
  this.documentService
    .downloadDocument((<Document>element).serialnumber, query)
    .pipe(
      filter(res => !!res),
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
      const fileName = `${(<Document>element).serialnumber}.pdf`;
      downloadBlob([res], fileName, 'application/pdf');
    });
}
```

My document service is:
...

```
   downloadDocument(serialNumber: string, query: 
  string) {
   const url = someURL(serialNumber, query);
   return this.dataService.asyncRequest(
   RequestTypes.GET,
   url,
   null,
   ServerHosts.TDocSERVER,
   {
     responseType: 'arraybuffer'
   }
  );
```

My other attempt was to creade DocumentDownloadActions file, define REQUEST/SUCCESS/FAILURE and then isLoading= true when the function is called and then as before end when there is a file or error.

```
  this.someDownloadService.get('someApiUrl', 
  somePayload).pipe(
   map((res) => {
   this.dispatch(new DownloadSuccessAction());
     return res;
  }),
  catch((err) => {
  this.dispatch(new DownloadFailureAction());
  })
```

Would listening to the HTTP call be a better method of doing this since I could match the progress bar to the network progress using Value?

Answer (score 0):

You can show or hide the progress bar using an `*ngIF="isLoading"`. I have simple scenario implemented to show the functionality. There is input and a search button. What ever the user enter, and on click search button, an API call is instantiated and the return data from API is displayed. On click, I am setting `this.isLoading=true` and once we get the API response, I am setting that to false i.e `this.isLoading=false`. 
Code snippet:

```
public onSearch(): void {
this.isLoading=true;
this.searchItems = [];
const tag: string = this.searchItem;

this.sampleService
  .search(tag)
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)),
    first()
  )
  .subscribe(
    results => {
      this.searchItems = results.query.search;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log('Error: '. error);
    }
  );
 }
```

In HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Search something" [(ngModel)]="searchItem"/><button 
 (click)="onSearch()">Search</button>
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="isLoading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>

<hr>

<h2>Search result:</h2>

<div *ngIf="searchItems && searchItems.length>0">
 <div *ngFor="let item of searchItems">
  <h4>{{item?.title}}</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please find the code sample in below link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-mat-progress-bar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Demo url:

https://angular-sf-mat-progress-bar.stackblitz.io

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that worked however the progress bar is not going away when the download starts. I console.log the boolean and it is showing as false. I added my progress bar like this                                                                         
           <div *ngIf="document.files.length > 1">
           <mat-progress-bar 
            *ngIf ="isdl"
             mode = "indeterminate">
            </mat-progress-bar> 
            </div>